# I dont get what i should in for loop (wrong numbers)

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop, numbers

The problem is of programming nature, I dont seem to get numbers I want. Meaning, my programm prints random numbers for me. I would really appreciate some help. Its really important to me:)

```
g = 0
pocz = 0
kon = 0

plikk = open('JV storage length.txt','r')
plik = open('JV storage.txt','r')
liniak = plikk.readlines()
linia = plik.readlines()

for g in range(0, 3):
    a = liniak[g]
    spl = a.split()

    h = spl[0]
    j = spl[1]
    kon += int(pocz) + int(h) 
    print(pocz)
    print(kon)
    pocz += int(kon) + int(j)
```

h and j are given properly as I wanted(each pair below is representation of one reptition of loop):

```
h = 2 
j = 3
h = 1 
j = 5
h = 1 
j = 3
```

And then I get results of running the code and only first line is what I wanted:

```
pocz = 0 
kon = 2
pocz = 5 
kon = 8
pocz = 18 
kon = 27
```

Cause from my math it should be:

```
pocz = 0 
kon = 2
pocz = 5 
kon = 2
pocz = 11 
kon = 12
```

Or am I missing something? If yes can someone please tell me how to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what `pocz` or `kon` is supposed to mean, what the purpose of the calculation is, or why you expect the result that you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you abuse `+=` here. Could you try

```
kon = int(pocz) + int(h) 
print(pocz)
print(kon)
pocz = int(kon) + int(j)
```

The output I get is:

```
0
2
5
6
11
12
```

So it looks like your anticipated output but not exactly. Could you please check your math?

Comment: Good to know :) Could you then vote it up or accept it as answer please?